# jquery button with .click and .load not working correctly

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a small problem with a jquery function and I can't figure out where I'm going wrong with it, I'm using .load to pull another page into a div for the second time using a button with a .click() function. The problem here is when I click the button the data I want flashes up and is then replaced with the data that is loaded when I first navigate to the page, however if I bind the .click to:

```
<p>peter paragraph</p>
```

The page will load fine without incident.

The jquery function is this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("p").click(function(){
                alert("buttonthe1st");
                $('#jam').load('register.php');
                alert("buttonthe2nd");
            }); 
        });
```

I was using the alerts to test to see if it was working originally, the function appears to be working a long with the actual load event when I tested them with the paragraph and when I tried them in googles developer console.

As I typed the above out I just realised when I was testing it, the URL and the page refreshed even if there was no function or onclick even tied to the button in question. Which explains why I'm having this problem now, is there a way to resolve this?

P.S. I appologise for making this so vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a little  confused as to why clicking on a paragraph element would cause a page to reload but if you are in fact talking about a button element you might find the [preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) function helpful. Try using that within the function you are binding to "onclick" and see if it makes any difference

Comment: Appologies for the confusion I was talking about a button. I just tried your suggestion but no dice. Using the code below appeared to stop the alerts working as well. Firefox flags it as _'event.preventDefault' is not a function_ however I thought I was using it in the same context as the documentation describes.


`$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#register').click(function(event)
{


     event.preventdefault();

     alert("buttonthe1st");

     $('#jam').load('register.php');

     alert("buttonthe2nd");

    }); 

   });`

Comment: preventDefault() with a capital D